# Glide 4 - Load from remote after loading from cache

Tags: android, caching, android-glide

I've a custom `Loader`, `DataFetcher` and `LoaderFactory` to load images from a NDK library. Then I create a signature to cache the data so it loads fast to the user.

However, I want to have the following behavior:

**1.** Load the cached image if available

**2.** Get the image from `remote`

**3.** Load the new image and save it to cache

Here's my current implementation:

```
   GlideApp.with(imageView)
        .load(customObject)
        .downsample(DownsampleStrategy.CENTER_INSIDE)
        .error(R.drawable.img_error)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .into(this)
```

That only shows me the cached image, and if there's none, then it gets it from `remote` and caches it.

Comment: I guess that you need to provide your cached image as a placeholder then.